# How to open modal or tooltip from a particular position of screen in React Native?

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, tooltip, react-native-modal

I am trying to open a modal on click of a button and that modal should open on top of that button (refer screenshot). I can place the button anywhere on the screen (mostly right aligned to the screen).

**Image 1 : before clicking on button**

[image: Image 2 : After clicking on button]

**Image 2 : After clicking on button:**
[image: Image 1 : Before clicking on button]

Answer (score 1):

This lib will work for you that will open a pop up right on your element.

https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu

Answer (score 0):

It is more like context menu popup or create custom popup menu on click of button click

This may helpful !
https://reactnativeexample.com/extensible-popup-context-menu-for-react-native/
https://aboutreact.com/react-native-popup-menu/
I hope it helps you to resolve an issue.

Thank you